# How do I Declaratively pass a ASP.NET UserControl's public property to a child UserControl

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls

I'm trying to clean up an old ASP.NET app at work...

I've got a parent UserControl called `FailedBatchPanel.ascx` that is defined like:

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="FailedBatchPanel.ascx.cs" Inherits="Controls_FailedBatchPanel" %>
<%@ Register TagPrefix="dashboard" TagName="FailedBatch" Src="~/Controls/FailedBatchControl.ascx" %>
<%@ Import Namespace="System" %>

<div class="panel panel-default" id="failedBatchesPanel">
  <div class="panel-heading">
    <h4 class="panel-title">
      <a class="accordion-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" 
         <data-parent="#<%=ParentId %>" href="#<%=PanelId %>">
        <%=Title %>
      </a>
    </h4>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="<%=PanelId %>" class="panel-collapse collapse">
  <div class="panel-body">
    <dashboard:FailedBatch runat="server" 
      ID="failedClaims" 
      BatchType='<%$ Code: BatchType %>'/>
  </div>
</div>
```

The child control is `FailedBatch.ascx` and simply contains an asp:Repeater with databinding.

The Parent Control, FailedBatchPanel, is called as follows:

```
<dashboard:FailedBatchPanel runat="server" 
    Title="SomeTitle" 
    ParentId="categories" 
    PanelId="collapseOne" 
    BatchType="goober"/>
```

I want to pass the BatchType defined declaratively as above to the child control that is embedded in FailedBatchPanel.

As you can see from the example above, I've tried using the `<%$ Code: ... %> CodeExpressionBuilder as defined by InfinitiesLoop at http://weblogs.asp.net/infinitiesloop/archive/2006/08/09/The-CodeExpressionBuilder.aspx

In every case that I've tried, the BatchType public property defined in FailedBatch is always null at Page_Load

I've tried:

- `BatchType="<%# BatchType %>"`  -- got Null
- `BatchType='<%# BatchType %>'`  -- got Null
- `BatchType="<%= BatchType %>"`  -- in this case I got the literal "<%= BatchType %>" instead of null
- `BatchType="<%$ Code: BatchType %> -- got Null

I'm stumped and need help. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you missing a "less than" in the following statement (?): dashboard:FailedBatch runat="server"

Comment: sorry, cut/paste error - fixed now

Comment: What type is BatchType... string?

Comment: Yes. public string BatchType { get; set }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the DataBind syntax we are able to get a result.

`BatchType='<%# BatchType %>'`

However, as you noted this returns nothing. You need to include code telling the control to databind so that `BatchType` will be evaluated:

```
<% failedClaims.DataBind%>
```

This may be placed anywhere within your parent usercontrol.

Comment: It's true that "you need to include code telling the control to databind".  But using an ASP-style embedded code block '<%...%>' is not the best way to do it - it won't execute the DataBind until the Render phase, which in the general case might be too late for the UserControl to make use of the properties that have been set.

Comment: @Joe I never pretended it was the best way... I would do this in the code behind. Perhaps I should have indicated that.